# Generalization of D'Alembert formula to include non continuous traveling impulses?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, wave-equation

We know that the classical, one dimensional wave equation
\begin{equation*}
u_{tt}= c^2 u_{xx}
\end{equation*}
with initial conditions
\begin{equation*}
u(x,0)= f(x)\ , \qquad u_t(x,0)= g(x) 
\end{equation*}
where $c>0$ is constant, have solutions given by D'Alambert formula:
\begin{equation*} u(x, t)= \frac{1}{2}\big(f(x+ ct)+ f(x- ct) \big)+ \frac{1}{2c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} g(s)\,ds 
\end{equation*}
In the classical sense, that is, under some differentiability conditions of $f$ and $g$ (what are they ? $C^1,\ C^2$ ?) , $u$ is twice differentiable both with respect to $x$ and $t$ and satisfies the wave equation.

The same formula suggests that there might be other solutions as well, in a 'weak' sense, for example :
$$u(x,t)= F(x-ct) + G(x+ct)$$
can be verified to describe physical wave functions even when $F, G$ are discontinuous.
$F$ describes a right traveling wave, and $G$ a left traveling wave. 
It seems like in this case, $u$ satisfies the wave equation as a distribution (?)

I am looking for a good reference on this matter.
How is D'alembert formula generalized and how it is explained with distribution theory ?

Comment: Sometimes I wonder all these books about PDEs and they don't include such an important fact! is it because it is hard or is it because simply they forgot to include it?

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered in another post

[Show that D'Alembert solution gives distributional solution to the wave-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4188048/show-that-dalembert-solution-gives-distributional-solution-to-the-wave-equation)

It is indeed a distributional solution under far weaker conditions.